# How does "CPU Thermal Throttle" work?

Tags: cpu, temperature, cpu-throttling

I have an `AMD FX-6300` CPU and an `ASRock 970 Pro3 R2.0` motherboard with an `American Megatrends version P1.0` BIOS. The BIOS has an option for *CPU Thermal Throttling* which can be *disabled*, can be set to *auto*, or can be set to a percentage (12%, 25%, etc) and it defaults to *auto*. From what I understand, this option will slow down the CPU if the temperature gets too high. But what I don't understand is the meaning of the percentages.

What happens when I set CPU Thermal Throttling to a percentage like 25% ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/565347/how-does-windows-limit-the-cpu-power-options-battery-saving/565352#565352) for info on how CPU throttle themselves:

the percentage refers to how much of the total capacity can be reduced when a thermal threshold is reached. by using 25%, you are telling it to reduce your CPU's clock multiplier to approximately 75% of its normal maximum value. Auto would presumably adjust the percentage based on how effective the throttling is in controlling the temperature.

EG a 4GHZ cpu (a 100Mhz chip and a 40x clock multiplier) would reduce the multiplier to 30x (75% of 40x) and the resulting total frequency would drop to 3Ghz.