# Games lag when charger disconnected

Tags: performance, lenovo-laptop, gaming

I recently bought a Lenovo Z51-70 which has 5yh Gen i7 and 8GB RAM with 4GB AMD Tropo X2 Graphics. With this configuration it should play almost every high end game but it only happens when I connect a charger. As soon as I disconnect it the Games start lagging. I've contacted Lenovo support regarding this and they've asked me to install some drivers which  didn't work. Finally I've decided to go it's service center this Saturday but just want to know if anyone else had this issue lately and what can I do to solve it.

Comment: Be sure your power configurations are set properly.  If your AC plug isn't connected it means you are running on a battery, by default, Windows will run differently while on a  battery.  Configure your system to run identically and the problem should go away.

Comment: So you have a laptop? Check whether your CPU or Graphics Card has some power savings mode and simply disable it. This is usually used to reach longer battery life but sacrifice some performance.

Comment: @DavidVernon - If you are linking to an existing question.  I can only assume the answer(s) to that question also answer this question.  Of course I highly suspect when the charger is being removed Windows is switching to the iGPU which means the Power Options are indeed relevant.  If you suspect his system is being throttled how is the question not a duplicate?

Comment: @Ramhound yes my answer could have include more reasoning as to why I linked. The link provides partial (but not full) answer to the question. Now editing to raise quality

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your CPU might be being throttled when you are running on battery power: a feature of Windows' power saving.

CPU throttling can be configured in 'Power Options', as per:

[How does windows "limit" the CPU (Power Options / Battery saving)](https://superuser.com/questions/565347/how-does-windows-limit-the-cpu-power-options-battery-saving)

However, your machine could also be configured to use its AMD GPU when plugged into mains power and the Intel integrated graphics when running from battery.

You'll need to check AMD's configuration software for this setting - It will be called 'Dynamic Switchable Graphics'.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but note the OP stated he has an AMD Tropo X2. Assuming he means the XT2, this appears to be a dedicated GPU.

Comment: Fair cop, found a page that stated (incorrectly) that this laptop was Intel integrated only.

Comment: Please don't post a link to a potential duplicate as an answer. The correct thing to do is flag the question: flag > a duplicate. Then the OP can accept the duplicate and reviewers with VTC (vote to close) privileges will do the necessary.

Comment: In addition link only answers (if the link is not a potential duplicate) are discouraged: the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.