# How to globally limit CPU execution cap on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, cpu, fedora, cpu-usage

My AMD FX 8320 has a bad habit of crashing down the OS when it is doing CPU intensive work, like *CG rendering* or *program compilation*.

On Windows, to overcome this issue, what I used to do was limit it's execution in Power Options to 90%. Somewhat as shown in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/565347/103134).

[image]

---

Is there a way to limit CPU execution cap to 90% in Linux?

I have researched on the internet about this, [most of](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cpu-usage-limiter-for-linux/) the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386945/limiting-certain-processes-to-cpu-linux) talk about limiting it on the [process basis](https://www.maketecheasier.com/limit-cpu-usage-of-any-process-in-linux/) or [core basis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23106/how-to-limit-a-process-to-one-cpu-core-in-linux). I want it to be global. Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: This Windows setting controls your CPU frequency. On Linux, this functionality is called “Frequency scaling governors”.

Comment: You're looking for `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/{scaling_governor,scaling_max_freq}`

Comment: Arch Linux has a guide on setting maximum clock speeds: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling and RedHat also has a guide: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/power_management_guide/cpufreq_governors. In RedHat it looks like the p-state can be configured to a maximum power percentage similarly to Windows. FYI my Google search was "fedora cpu power state limit" just to get you running in the right direction.

Comment: Have you looked at increasing your cooling/airflow instead?