# Limit Turbo Boost of CPU

Tags: laptop, cpu, turbo-boost

So, I've just bought a new Laptop with an i7-1065G7 CPU, which runs at a base clock speed of 1.3 GHz and is able to go up to 3.9 GHz when turbo-boosting.

1 TB SSD, 16 GB RAM, good integrated and discrete graphics, feels nice, looks nice. **BUT**... it is too loud, and I haven't even done anything with it yet. Whenever the CPU goes beyond 3 GHz the fan is just screaming.

I don't think I can work with this for the next four to five years. Right now my only hope is that I can somehow limit the GHz count when the CPU goes into Turbo mode, though I'm not sure how to do that. I'd also appreciate any alternative solutions.

Comment: Are you using a fan speed controller? Is it a stock HSF?

Comment: @spikey_richie Everything is just as packaged. It's an `Acer Aspire 5 A515-55G`. (I.e. I'm not using a controller or anything like that.)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it was a laptop.

Comment: If you use Windows, you can limit "Maximum processor state" in your advanced power plan settings, like so: https://superuser.com/questions/565347/how-does-windows-limit-the-cpu-power-options-battery-saving

Comment: @Nassbirne Thank you, I will check that out.

Comment: @Nassbirne Btw. I completely forgot to say that that really helped out. Now the base clock speed is often under 1 GHz, which is kind of unfortunate, but I'm still happy with the performance. Thanks a lot.